# zabbix smtp check fails with working smtp server

Tags: exim, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I use a zabbix 2.2.7 to monitor our servers. I mostly use zabbix-agent with active checks as many of the monitored machines are behind NAT.

One of the checks on all linux servers is `net.tcp.service[smtp]` (used as active agent check), and it works on all servers but one. Other `net.tcp.service` active checks work on the server just fine.
The monitored server runs exim4 (stock debian buster), and can receive and send e-mails just fine.

I enabled debugging for the given zabbix-agent, and this is the most informative line I got from it:

```
28545:20200204:103404.692 for key [net.tcp.service[smtp]] received value [0]
```

Which is not informative at all. :(

One anomaly I can detect is that if I telnet into exim, it gives the greeting line really slowly (about 15s).

My questions are:

- How can I debug what the zabbix-agent does during the `net.tcp.service[smtp]` check?
- How can I change the behaviour of that check?

EDIT: The problem really was the slowness of the server, which was caused by a bad primary DNS (it took that many seconds to start to use the secondary). However, my questions still stand, as it would have been much easier to debug if I could have just got the info that the check timed out in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on zabbix 4.4 with exim.
I changed smtp check item key  
from `net.tcp.service[smtp]`  
to  `net.tcp.service[smtp,127.0.0.1]` in Template App SMTP Service to connect `127.0.0.1` instead of zabbix-agent public IP.